# Rotating View in android with one end as the rotation point

Tags: android

When using 'android:Rotation' the angular value given rotates the view with the middle of the view as the center.

Now, I have a rectangular view and I want the rotation to be done with one end being fixed and instead of the middle of the rectangle this end should be the center of the rotation.

But going through the documentation of Android for hours I cannot find any solution to this problem.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/rotate_view"
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
```

This is my XML part for the view. How can this be rotated with one end as being fixed done?